# Labelling with scale_fill_stepsn(), "Breaks and labels are different lengths"

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the plot I have:

[image]

I used this code (including sample data):

```
# dummy data
df_test <- data.frame(long = rep(447030:447050, 21),
                      lat = rep(5379630:5379650, each=21),
                      z = rnorm(21*21))

# plot
ggplot(df_test) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=long, y = lat, fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    limits = c(-3, 3), breaks = seq(-3, 3, 1), # labels = seq(-3, 3, 1),
    colors = c("#ff6f69", "grey90", "#00aedb"))
```

I would like the legend to show the maximum and minimum value (-3, +3). But when I uncomment the label-code `labels = seq(-3, 3, 1),` I get an error:

> Error: Breaks and labels are different lengths"

Is this a bug or am I misusing the function? (aka: Is it a bug or a feature?) Either way: Do you guys know any workaround / solution for this issue? Maybe something with `override.aes()` (I am not really good with that function)?

R version: 4.1.0 | ggplot2 version: 3.3.5

(Maybe related: [Breaks and labels of different lengths scale_size_binned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67585114/breaks-and-labels-of-different-lengths-scale-size-binned))

**Edit:** If I install ggplot2 version 3.3.3, the last box in the legend is bigger somehow (which I don't like either).

[image]

Comment: I ran your code and I don't run into the error you mention, regardless whether I uncomment the labels bit or not. It also just shows the -3 and +3 labels.

Comment: That's weird, what R & ggplot2 version are you using? Also thanks for checking!

Comment: I'm using R 4.0.5 on Windows 10 with ggplot2 v3.3.3. If I update to v3.3.5 I run into the same error though, so it might be a regression bug.

Comment: I browsed ggplot2's github a bit to find out what might've caused this and it appears [this PR](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4423) has broken your use case. I think it might be best report a new issue with this bug.

Comment: Thank you, I submitted the issue on github and linked the issue you suggested: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a workaround for what I think might be a bug, but you might tweak the breaks a little bit to add/subtract a very small value:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df_test <- data.frame(long = rep(447030:447050, 21),
                      lat = rep(5379630:5379650, each=21),
                      z = rnorm(21*21))

# plot
smallvalue <- 10 * .Machine$double.eps

ggplot(df_test) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=long, y = lat, fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    limits = c(-3, 3), 
    breaks = c(-3 + smallvalue, -2:2, 3 - smallvalue), 
    labels = seq(-3, 3, 1),
    colors = c("#ff6f69", "grey90", "#00aedb")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### EDIT:

Alternatively, you can set the inner breaks and use a function for the `labels` argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df_test <- data.frame(long = rep(447030:447050, 21),
                      lat = rep(5379630:5379650, each=21),
                      z = rnorm(21*21))

# plot
smallvalue <- 10 * .Machine$double.eps

ggplot(df_test) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=long, y = lat, fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    limits = c(-3, 3), 
    breaks = -2:2,
    labels = function(x) {x}, # Just display the breaks
    show.limits = TRUE,
    colors = c("#ff6f69", "grey90", "#00aedb")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but can I somehow bring ggplot to then not display the lowest/highest color on the scale?

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, I just needed `show.limits = TRUE`. Nice. It works perfectly. :)